# How to send offline data to server once network has been connected?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-jetpack

I'm trying to figure out how to send offline data to the server using a POST request when the device is connected to wifi or data.

How do I implement this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that it will be necessary to monitor when the user will be connected. An easy way is using the `ConnectivityManager`, but the `minSdk` must be `24` or higher.

Note: I'm assuming you're using `Kotlin` because you didn't specify the language but used the `Compose` tag before post edit.

```kotlin
enum class ConnectivityStatus {
    Available, Losing, Lost, Unavailable
}
```

```kotlin
class ConnectivityObserver(context: Context) {
    private val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
            as ConnectivityManager

    fun observe(): Flow<ConnectivityStatus> = callbackFlow {
        val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                launch { send(ConnectivityStatus.Available) }
            }

            override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)
                launch { send(ConnectivityStatus.Losing) }
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                launch { send(ConnectivityStatus.Lost) }
            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable()
                launch { send(ConnectivityStatus.Unavailable) }
            }
        }

        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback)

        awaitClose {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        }
    }.distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

In this code example I was using an `enum class` with some possible connection states and a class that returns a `flow` with the respective states according to the user's connection through `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`.

Now we can observe the states (preferably inside a `ViewModel`) and trigger the appropriate actions.

```kotlin
// class to handle Retrofit methods
class MyRepository {
    suspend fun doPost() {
        // post something
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// data class to hold states
data class MyState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val hasPendingActions: Boolean = false,
    val connectivityStatus: ConnectivityStatus = ConnectivityStatus.Unavailable,
    // and so on...
)
```

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(
    private val connectivityObserver: ConnectivityObserver,
    private val myRepository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var state by mutableStateOf(MyState())
        private set

    init {
        observeConnectivity()
    }

    // to call on screen
    fun doThings() {
        if (state.connectivityStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Available) {
            state = state.copy(isLoading = true)
            myRepository.doPost()
        } else state = state.copy(hasPendingActions = true)
    }

    private fun observeConnectivity() = viewModelScope.launch {
        connectivityObserver.observe().collect { status ->
            when (status) {
                ConnectivityStatus.Available -> {
                    state = state.copy(connectivityStatus = status)
                    if (state.hasPendingActions) {
                        state = state.copy(isLoading = true, hasPendingActions = false)
                        myRepository.doPost()
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    state = state.copy(connectivityStatus = status)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://youtu.be/TzV0oCRDNfM) is a YouTube video where I took the code example using the `ConnectivityManager` with `callbackFlow`.

Comment: thanks, If I implement multiple POST requests with a lot of data, should I be using work manager? if so how do I implement the above code with work manager?